# Transferring an Xcode project to another computer with all files/frameworks

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, transfer, projects

I am trying to copy over my Xcode project from one computer to another but it seems to lose frameworks and the locations for the images although i copied those too.

PS I am using xcode and coding an app with a friend. Is there a useful source that can help us both code at once/ transfer code files.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try transferring everything from plists to the storyboard. I did this with a friend of mine and it only took about 20 minutes for the code to build and run successfully on his own laptop. the biggest issue is going to be transferring the files that Xcode is going to have to search for, and making sure that the search paths match with where you save the new files.

SDK's and images are difficult because of this path issue - make sure you find where the pictures are supposed to be searched for then add the images there.

Just take your time - even write down where each file should go **or** where you have put it and you should get it working. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

You have to select relative paths in your project for your resources/frameworks (e.g. Relative to group). If you have absolute paths, it won't work on a different computer. Also check in the Build Settings of your target the Framework, Library and Header search paths.